# projector augmented waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-functional-theory

I am starting out with density functional theory from an engineering perspective. Could anyone help me understand what the difference is between USPP (ultra-soft pseudopotential) and PAW (projector augmented wave)? A physical/logical explanation (if possible) would be more helpful for me than a full mathematical description. Thanks!

Comment: 3 years is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.